# como mudar uma coluna que e chave primaria para identity?

Tags: banco-de-dados

Bom eu fiz uma tabela no sqlserver e coloquei a chave primaria como int normal porem preciso alterar ela pra identity. como faço??

Comment: precisa excluir a coluna atual e incluir uma nova, como `identity`

Comment: valeu me ajudo dms !

Answer (score 2):

Você pode alterar via comando ou via Management Studio.
Via comando você terá que remover a coluna e adiciona-lá novamente:

```
ALTER TABLE Cliente
DROP COLUMN Id   

ALTER TABLE Cliente
ADD ID INT NOT NULL Identity(1,1)
```

via Management Studio:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado ajudou muito!!